# How to implement unique user data

Tags: java, android, sqlite, validation

I have an android app that organises a list of items. Each item has an id field that has to be user input and unique. This id is stored in an SQlitedatabase.
I'm wondering whats the best way to validate user input to make sure the ID's are unique?

Comment: You query that ID that was just inputted if the result of the query is none or 0 then that is a unique ID

Comment: Would that slow down the performance too much?

Comment: then there would be no way to tell if the id is unique and that is just a single query that wont affect much

Comment: Could you show me a basic look of what the query would look like?

Answer (score 0):

Having human's control IDs is generally a bad idea. IDs are best left to be auto-incremented by the database. That being said, there is an approache that may help achieve what you wish.

Have a "hidden" ID that the database manages alongside a visible, "fake", ID that users can manipulate, and make the hidden ID the primary key. This ensures data integrity (here). You still need a separate task to check that the user input a unique fake ID, but this is not avoidable if you want user-entered IDs.

I recommend re-visiting your requirement to have users enter IDs. If you can do without this requirement, you will save a lot of headaches with this table.

Comment: I know, trust me it would so much less of a headache if I could just implement a primary key. But for this particular scenario, I was asked to allow user manipulation of the ID. It's not for commercial use, so it's also a good learning experience. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: I hear you. In that case, you could elegantly handle the failure that will occur when the user tries to add/change the ID to be one that already exists. You could have your program accept the request, and do it's own check to see if a record with that ID already exists. It could tell the user that the request is invalid because of a duplicate ID. Be careful not to give too much information away to the user. Maybe an ID already existing is private info! Respond with something like "The request is invalid" in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ajax technology. When the user input the data and clicked enter or the textBox become unfocused, then javascrpit sends an ajax request to the back-end to query whether the data has occur. if yes, then give a tip to the user.